# Appium cannot find any elements after close dialog

Tags: popup, appium

Once I dismiss the pop up window of 'Forgot Password' from the 'Login' page then I cannot access any element of the Login Page. I always get "Element Not Found" issue.
But if I try to access all the element before I dismiss the pop up, then it's accessible. Problem start once I dismiss any pop up window.

Appium Version: 1.6.3
Android Device: MI A1
Android OS Version: 8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for this issue. You have to minimize the app and maximize again. After that Appium will get all the ID's and you can continue the test.

```
   public static void minimizeMaximize() {
try {
driver.runAppInBackground(10);
((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity("appPackage", "appActivity");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

You have to enter your app package name and activity name to maximize the app.
For Eg:

```
 public static void minimizeMaximize() {
try {
driver.runAppInBackground(10);
((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity("com.example.test", "com.example.LaunchApp");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

This will definitely work.

Comment: can you tell why this problem comes, why the appium not able to get the ids after dialog dismiss. I am also facing this problem.

Comment: Is there any permanent solution? or is it due to an app wrong way of coding for dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

Shweta Sankhe

i have tried your answer

In my case, I didn't need to use 
`((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity("com.example.test", "com.example.LaunchApp")`;

```
public static void minimizeMaximize() {
try {
driver.runAppInBackground(10);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```